# Generate labels for predictive model using featuretools

Tags: featuretools

I'm currently working through the feature tools demo (https://github.com/Featuretools/predict_next_purchase/blob/master/Tutorial.ipynb) using my own data.  I've created an entity set, and am trying to first create the labels.  The notebook references import utils, but that is not being installed w/ feature tools.  Is this a separate module I need to install?

python 2.7
pip install featuretools

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `utils.py` file is specific to the demo repository not the Featuretools library.
You should clone or download the whole repo before running the tutorial.

The file itself is here: https://github.com/Featuretools/predict_next_purchase/blob/master/utils.py

The `make_labels` function is in that file at this line:
https://github.com/Featuretools/predict_next_purchase/blob/9cab9b28c94c43c69d7fb75b6ed92b3dd4cfb72d/utils.py#L66

Once you have the file locally, you can modify it for your specific use case.